# Getting Error ORA-00933

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I have found some question about this error which was previously asked but those are not perfectly what i am looking.
This is why I have to asked here.

I am getting `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` error while running this query.

```
select T.course_id from course as T 
where unique (select R.course_id from section as R
              where T.course_id= R.course_id and R.year = 2009);
```

**Here is the screenshot:**

[image]

Now, what's wrong with this query ? How do I solve this error?

Comment: What is `unique` supposed to be doing?

Comment: The `unique` construct returns the value true if the argument
sub query contains no duplicate tuples.

Comment: . . I have not come across this operator.  Can you point me to a reference in the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `as`.  Oracle does not recognize that for table aliases.  However, I don't understand what `distinct` is doing; perhaps you mean `exists`:

```
select T.course_id
from course T 
where exists (select R.course_id
              from section R
              where T.course_id= R.course_id and R.year = 2009
             );
```

EDIT:

If you want to validate that all courses in the subquery are distinct and if the database does not support `unique` (which may be an ANSI operator but I'm not sure it is implemented elsewhere):

```
select T.course_id
from course T 
where 1 =  (select (case when count(R.course_id) = count(distinct R.course_id) and
                              count(R.courseJ_id) = count(*)
                         then 1 else 0
                    end)
            from section R
            where T.course_id= R.course_id and R.year = 2009
           );
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I appreciate the help. This query works perfectly. But it would be great if there will be another solution in which query includes `unique` construct but showing no errors.

Comment: @BlueeandRed . . . You can try `unique` instead of `exists` in the first version.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: it gets error `ORA-00936: missing expression` using `unique` instead of `exists`.

Comment: @BlueeandRed . . . I didn't think it would work.  Oracle doesn't recognize `unique` as an operator (although it can be used as a modifier with `select`).